# Paging and sorting by enumeration

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, enumeration, pageable

My service is returning a page of elements, and I want to be able to sort it by many fields.
So far I can sort it by all fields except this enumeration field:

```
enum ActionStatusEnum {
    TO_DO("ToDo"),
    ROUGH_DRAFT("Brouillon"),
    WAITING_FOR_VALIDATION("En attente de validation"),
    VALIDATED("Validée"),
    ......

    private String label;

    ActionStatusEnum(String value) {
        label = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
```

So far my sort looks like that (status being the enumeration field)

```
for (String sort : sorts) {
            switch(sort) {
                case "createDate":
                    s = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "creationDate");
                    mySort = mySort == null ? s : mySort.and(s);
                    break;
                case "rubric":
                    s = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "task.rubric");
                    mySort = mySort == null ? s : mySort.and(s);
                    break;

                ........ // other cases

                case "status":
                    s = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "status");
                    break;
                default :
                    s = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "submissionDate");
                    mySort = mySort == null ? s : mySort.and(s);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

As you expect whenever I sort by status, it gets sorted by alphabetic order; while I need to order it as it is declared in the enumeration (TO_DO then ROUGH_DRAFT then WAITING_FOR_VALIDATION ....) .
Is there any solution to that, like making my custom enumeration ordering or something that way. Thank you in advance

Comment: Where do you read values from ? DB, File or any kind of other memories ? Maybe you can think of the receive values already ordered besides sorting here ?

Comment: @Hayra from DB, but i can't just get pre-ordered values, cause the user is the one to choose wich sorts to use and their order of using, like he can choose to order by date then status...